# Ubuntu crashing when I open Firefox

Tags: 12.10, kernel, firefox

It's a fresh install. I installed proprietary drivers for my GTX 670, but it screwed up the resolution, so I reverted back to the open-source drivers.

I then got a lot of messages saying an internal error had occurred and to send the report.

Now when I open Firefox it crashes Ubuntu 12.10 to a black screen for a couple seconds, then puts me back at the login screen.

The black screen says

```
* Stopping save kernel messages
* Starting CUPS printing spooler/server

* Checking battery state...

* Stopping System V runlevel compatibility

* Starting
```

I am unsure what is happening. I reinstalled Ubuntu 3 times and keep running across this error. Should I try Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 1):

Please install the appropriate drivers version by using the appropriate tool.

Go to `System Settings`, and launch `Software Origins`. Then, on the `Additional drivers` tab, check the `nvidia-experimental-310` entry and click on `Apply changes`.

When done, reboot your computer.